# How can 256 be represented by a char?

Tags: c

I ran the following code in xcode in to my surprise the answer was 256.
Since char is only 8 bits long i expected this to be 0.
Dumping the 1 in the 8 place.
Can someone explain what is going on?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char i = 0x80;
    printf("%d\n", i<<1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is being promoted to an integer when you do `i << 1`. For example, `SHL` works on 32 bit words (even though your c type is 8 bit) in x86 so the shifted bit isn't discarded out of the 32 bit register. When you print this region with with `"%d"`, you get `256`. If you want to left shift with `unsigned char`, you can always do `(i << x) & 0xff`.

Comment: or cast to unsigned char, or assign to an unsigned char.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with "registers" or "SHR". There's a very straight-forward answer in C itself.

Comment: I just gave the reason why promotion is required! You can also type cast as robert mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

It is being promoted to an integer, which can contain the value of `256` just fine. A cast to `unsigned char` will give you the result you expected:

```
printf("%d\n", (unsigned char)(i<<1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, what is happening is that the intermediate result of `i<<1` is an integer, which can represent 256.